# Custom Validation Rule does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

Below is a code that does not work. I made it work without validation, I mean I set a criterion inside `MyClass`'s `set` and it did work. However, when I try a validation rule it does not work.

```
class MyClass
{
    private string num;

    public string MyString
    {
        get
        {                    
            return num;
        }
        set
        {
            num = value;             
        }
    }
}

public class MyValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        float num = System.Convert.ToSingle(value);

        // Is positive?
        if (num < 0)
        {                    
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Must be positive");
        }

        // Number is valid
        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
}

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    mc = new MyClass();
    Binding b = new Binding(mc.MyString);
    b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    b.ValidationRules.Add(new MyValidationRule());
    b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;

    MyTextBox.DataContext = mc;
}
```

Comment: Because that textBox is in another window. I was not able to do it with XAML.

Comment: I don't think you should be doing something like that...

Comment: Problem is accessing an instance in another window. How can I do this with XAML: `AnotherWindow.MyTextBox.DataContext = mc;`

Comment: You should not have a reference to another window, all you need should be linked via viewmodels or models, so if you need access to some property which may be visible in a related window the data context of your current window should have a reference to the datacontext of the related window, and the related window should bind to those properties as well.

Comment: May you provide something to read about what you said lastly?

Comment: This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) might be a good start, if you keep the seperations outlined you should end up with a proper data-design sooner or later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your binding seems broken. This:

```
Binding b = new Binding(mc.MyString);
```

...should be:

```
Binding b = new Binding("MyString");
```

Also i do not even see any call to [`SetBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.setbinding.aspx).

([How to debug bindings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx))

Comment: @ExitMusic: `mc.MyString` returns the string value of the `MyString` property, it can be anything. It will only create the correct binding if the value of `MyString` at that point is `"MyString"`.

Comment: yea sorry I looked at the code properly then realised i was being stupid : /

Comment: OK, I have changed it to `"MyString"` and added `SetBinding` and it worked. Thank you very much.